# What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I am supposed to meet a guy for a meeting at his office. Then got a message 1 hour before the meeting saying" I am available when you are " .  What does it mean ?

Answer (score 3):

It means that he is free to meet earlier than the time appointed for your meeting, and, if you are able, he would like to do so.